# Strange unmarshalling behavior with union in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, unmarshalling, unions

I want to export a C-like union into a byte array, like this :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct my_struct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 my_uint;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public bool other_field;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var test = new my_struct { my_uint = 0xDEADBEEF };
    byte[] data = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(test)];

    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(test, buffer, false);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, data, 0, data.Length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

    foreach (byte b in data)
    {
        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", b);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output we get (https://dotnetfiddle.net/gb1wRf) is `01 00 00 00` instead of  the expected `EF BE AD DE`.

Now, what do we get if we change the `other_field` type to `byte` (for instance) ?

Oddly, we get the output we wanted in the first place, `EF BE AD DE` (https://dotnetfiddle.net/DnXyMP)

Moreover, if we swap the original two fields, we again get the same output we wanted (https://dotnetfiddle.net/ziSQ5W)

Why is this happening? Why would the order of the fields matter ? Is there a better (reliable) solution for doing the same thing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an inevitable side-effect of the way a structure is marshaled.  Starting point is that the structure value is not blittable, a side-effect of it containing a *bool*.  Which takes 1 byte of storage in the managed struct but 4 bytes in the marshaled struct (UnmanagedType.Bool).

So the struct value cannot just be copied in one fell swoop, the marshaller needs to convert each individual member.  So the `my_uint` is first, producing 4 bytes.  The `other_field` is next, also producing 4 bytes at the exact same address.  Which overwrites everything that `my_uint` produced.

The *bool* type is an oddity in general, it *never* produces a blittable struct.  Not even when you apply `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]`.  Which in itself has an interesting effect on your test, you'll now see that the 3 upper bytes produced by `my_int` are preserved.  But the result is still junk since the members are still converted one-by-one, now producing a single byte of value 0x01 at offset 0.

You can easily get what you want by declaring it as a *byte* instead, now the struct is blittable:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct my_struct {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UInt32 my_uint;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        private byte _other_field;

        public bool other_field {
            get { return _other_field != 0; }
            set { _other_field = (byte)(value ? 1 : 0); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I admit that I don't have an authoritative answer for why `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` behaves this way, other than that clear it is doing more than just copying bytes. Rather, it must be interpreting the `struct` itself, marshaling each field individually to the destination via the normal rules for interpreting that field. Since `bool` is defined to only ever be one of two values, the non-zero value gets mapped to `true`, which marshals to raw bytes as `0x00000001`.

Note that if you really just want the raw bytes from the `struct` value, you can do the copying yourself instead of going through the `Marshal` class. For example:

```
var test = new my_struct { my_uint = 0xDEADBEEF };
byte[] data = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(test)];

unsafe
{
    byte* pb = (byte*)&test;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = pb[i];
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", data.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

Of course, for that to work you will need to enable `unsafe` code for your project. You can either do that for the project in question, or build the above into a separate helper assembly where `unsafe` is less risky (i.e. where you don't mind enabling it for other code, and/or don't care about the assembly being verifiable, etc.).

Comment: Arghhh, I just did this for fun without reading your answer completely :D DOH!

Comment: @leppie: BTDT. At least you had fun. :)